# How do you create a right-aligned suckerfish menu where top link is variable-width?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, nav, suckerfish

I have created a Son of Suckerfish (http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) CSS-based nav menu. The left side is normal Suckerfish where the top-level nav entry is the same width of the drop-downs.

On the right side of my menu I have several small icons for things like help and options that also have drop-down menus. The problem is I need to right-align them so they do not go off the page, because the icons are narrow and floated right.

Word picture time :)

```
_______________________________________________________
| menu-item    | menu-item    |       ____________| ? |
--------------------------------------| help item 1   |
                                      | help item 2   |
                                      | etc           |
                                      -----------------
```

What I did somewhat successfully was apply negative left margin to the inner  that holds the drop-down entries:

```
#nav li ul { width: 10em; margin-left: -10em; }
```

There's one problem, it ends up too far left:

```
_______________________________________________________
| menu-item    | menu-item    |  _________________| ? |
---------------------------------| help item 1   |-----
                                 | help item 2   |
                                 | etc           |
                                 -----------------
```

A simple solution would be to base my widths on px instead of em and reduce the negative left-margin by the width of my icon (16px), but that is hacky. It won't handle font zooming. Another trick I thought up would be to use margin-left:-9em; and make my icon element width:1em; but that seems a little wonky too. I'm hoping someone has a better idea!

Comment: It would really help if you could make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far.

Comment: The project I was doing that for died out I don't have time now. Surely people have done this a thousand times -- surprised no one had a quick answer. Maybe no one is using suckerfish/son of suckerfish style CSS menus these days.

Comment: With a test case, you'd have definitely got an answer (from me!). The general idea would have been: on `:hover` for the last `li`, set on `ul` something like `right: 0` or `right: -<width of containing li>px` or possibly `left: 100%`.

Comment: If you no longer need an answer for this can you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I put together a fiddle for this and found a solution... See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/7JMkp/.  Didn't have time to verify in all browsers.  Probably some IE tweaking needed.